# Is it possible to specify a delay for pod restart when Kubernetes liveness probe fails?

Tags: kubernetes, gunicorn

Got a simple REST API server built with python gunicorn, which runs multiple threads to accept requests. After running for some time, some of these threads crash. Got a script to detect the number of dead threads (using log files). Once this number crosses some threshold, we want to restart gunicorn. This script is configured to be used as [liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/).

The script works fine and restarts the pod as expected. But there are a few live threads that are still processing requests. Also, gunicorn keeps a backlog queue of accepted requests that it cannot process yet, since other requests are processing. Is there a way to specify a delay for the pod restart so the other running threads and the backlog requests have some time to finish processing?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu liveness probe itself restarts pods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a prestop hook. Offcial docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks)

How to use documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers).

You can also use terminationGracePeriodSeconds to allow graceful termination of pod.

Best Practices [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure graceful pod termination with `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: test
spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
        spec:
            containers:
              - name: test
                image: ...
            terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```